# Matching users Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, matching

[question solved] => I just made a silly mistake and forgot to add @match.save at the end of my method :)

I'm relatively new to RoR and the ActiveRecord architecture. I'm trying to build a simple app that can match 2 users together based on their interests. First here's the schema of my database:

[Link to my DB's schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljv5f.png)

or if you prefer here's the schema.rb file:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160612080318) do




 create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user1_id"
    t.integer  "user2_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "conversations", ["user1_id"], name: "index_conversations_on_user1_id", using: :btree
  add_index "conversations", ["user2_id"], name: "index_conversations_on_user2_id", using: :btree

  create_table "interests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user1_id"
    t.integer  "user2_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "matches", ["user1_id"], name: "index_matches_on_user1_id", using: :btree
  add_index "matches", ["user2_id"], name: "index_matches_on_user2_id", using: :btree

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "read_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  add_index "messages", ["conversation_id"], name: "index_messages_on_conversation_id", using: :btree
  add_index "messages", ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "user_interests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "interest_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "avatar_url"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "messages", "conversations"
  add_foreign_key "messages", "users"
  add_foreign_key "user_interests", "interests"
  add_foreign_key "user_interests", "users"
end
```

Just to test my models I didn't take into account the algorithm that will match users based on their interest. So here's my matches_controller.rb:

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @match = Match.new
  end

  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    @match.user1_id = current_user.id
    @match.user2_id = User.first.id 
  end


  private

  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:user1_id, :user2_id)
  end
end
```

my match model:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user1, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :user2, class_name: "User"

end
```

and finally my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_interests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :interests, through: :user_interests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matches, dependent: :destroy

  def conversations
    Conversation.includes(:messages)
                .where("user1_id = :id OR user2_id = :id", id: id)
                .order("messages.created_at DESC")
  end

  def other_user(conversation)
    conversation.users.include?(self) ? conversation.other_user(self) : nil
  end

  def unread_conversations
    conversations.select { |c| c.unread_messages?(self) }
  end

  def unread_conversations_count
    unread_conversations.count
  end

  def unread_conversations?
    unread_conversations_count > 0
  end

  def one_avatar_url
    avatar_url ? avatar_url : "http://placehold.it/64x64"
  end
end
```

I've tried to test my Match.create method in the console but got only nil for user1_id and user2_id. I've been looking all day long everywhere without being able to pinpoint what's wrong with my code.

Thanks a lot for helping me on this issue :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `@match.save` in the `create` method to persist the changes in the db?

Comment: Yes you're totally right! I was first using a `Match.create` in my method so I forgot to add the `@match.save`. It should be working now. Do you see anything wrong with my code. Thanks a lot for your help.